# CSS div next to div and width of second one

Tags: css

I am trying to display two divs next to each other. The first one is 200x200 pixels and the second is 10 pixels to the right of to the first one. It's 200 pixels high, and its width must fill the right of the page to the right.

I have this so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.div1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

div.div2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2">Test123</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works for the first two requirements, but when I set `width: 100%` then it goes below. If I set it to a number in pixels it seems to work though, but won't adjust as I change the size of the window. How can I fix this so the second element extends all the way to right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flex` on the parent, and set `.div2 { flex-grow: 1; }` to have it consume all of the available space left over from `.div1`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.div2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
```

Comment: Note that for IE this only works with 11 and later, and even there it's kind a buggy (<http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Aflex>). I'd also be wary of applying this to the body. Instead, I'd create a common parent for the two that has width:100%.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks. fyi the link is http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox, it has support back to IE10, and 97.61% support globally.

Answer (score 3):

you can use calc:

```
.div2 {
  width: calc(100% - 214px);
}
```

that is 100% minus 200 px, 10px margin, 4px border (2x left and right borders)

Comment: This doesn't work... (hint, you need to account for the border widths or use `box-sizing: border-box`)

Comment: @Michael Coker yes you're right, didn't see the border. will amend

Comment: cool, it's kind of a grey area since they didn't put the borders as requirements in the post, but they did use borders in their example code. I'd just hate them to plug your code into their example and they not know how to account for the border width and assume your solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```html
<html>    
<head>
    <style>
        #div1 {
            float:left;
            width:200px;
            border:1px solid red;
          min-height:200px;
        }
        #div2 {
            margin-left: 210px;
            border:1px solid green;
            min-height:200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>    
<body>
    <div id="div1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="div2">&nbsp;</div>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Tip 1**: Use percentage in both divs to add a total of 100%.

**Tip 2**: Use the max-width property, so that the second div can extend to no longer then a certain point.

**Tip 3**: Use the developer tools (inspect), select the second div and increase the pixels width until it reaches the total width of the page.